# What happens to an AVR UART's XCK pin when running in an asynchronous mode?

Tags: avr, uart

The question concerns AVR128DB32 but I don't happen to have a device available at hand to answer my own question by verify its behaviour on my workbench.

Reading [the data sheet for that microcontroller](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/AVR128DB28-32-48-64-DataSheet-DS40002247A.pdf) doesn't mention the XCK at all in the context of asynchronous operation. Does it keep its connection to the fractional Fractional Baud Rate Generator and keeps spewing out the UART's internal clock or does it get disconnected and is able to be used for a different output?

Comment: Look at the page 376.

Comment: Depends on how you configure the I/O Multiplexing. The XCKO signal *can* be output on PA2, PA6, PB2, etc, (depending on the specific UART) but doesn't have to be.

Comment: @brhans but if I want TX/RX to be at PA4/PA5 it PA6 has to have XCK, right? As far as I'm aware there is no way to select per-pin alternatives?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I can see the XCK connected to Baud Rate generator output on that diagram and I saw it before but I did wonder if that's the case only for synchronous operation or the async case as well.

Comment: Yeah I think you're right - I was thinking of a different micro.